# ImportError due to folder path of Python project

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyramid

My Pyramid app is located in a folder called back/. Because of this, I import modules by calling:

`from back import x`

Unfortunately, when deploying my app to Elastic Beanstalk, my Pyramid app is no longer located in a folder called back/. As a result, I end up getting the following error:

`ImportError: No module named back`

Because my project consists of multiple files, it will be very difficult for me to rename all imports. Is there a way of naming the module differently even if the folder is named differently?

Comment: Why is it so difficult to do search & replace in all files for `from back` -> `from <something>`? I'm usually using [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.9.2.html) for this.

Comment: I guess so. Still, it would be nice if there was an easier way.

Comment: It's not a folder it's a package.

Comment: I think [awk](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) can do this

Comment: I've decided to just do a search & replace, but I'll keep this open in case anyone has a better way of doing this.